# Alpine.js - sync computed field back to model

Tags: alpine.js

I have a form with some dynamic inputs, and I need to define a readonly computed field, which will have a value count from other fields. This I am doing using `x-bind:value='myFormulaFunction()'` and it shows the value on the field correctly, and it even updates live if the variables change.

The problem is how to sync this count value back to the model. Even when I define `x-model` on the field, it doesn't update with the value. And apparently no functions like `@change` and `@input` are triggered on the value update either, neither does `x-effect`.

I made a quick fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/janzikmund/cm3zqeyj/12/

I know I should probably make a get function to achieve this, but I am doing this within `x-for` of dynamically generated array and having the logic on the field itself would just be much more convenient. Anything I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that purpose you can use the [`$watch` magic method](https://alpinejs.dev/magics/watch) that actually supports watching for multiple variables. So when one of the variables changes, it updates the value of `count.sum`.

Note: `$watch` checks for each child attribute, so don't watch the whole `count` variable because it will cause an infinite loop.

```html
<script defer src="https://unpkg.com/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>
  <div x-data="{ count: { f1: 0, f2: 0, sum: 0} }"
       x-init="$watch('count.f1,count.f2', () => {count.sum = !isNaN(count.f1) && !isNaN(count.f2) ? parseInt(count.f1) + parseInt(count.f2) : 0})">
  <input type="number" x-model="count.f1">
  <input type="number" x-model="count.f2">
  <input type="text" readonly x-model="count.sum">
  <h2 x-text="count.sum"></h2>
</div>
```